# Unexpected keypress behavior with Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-devtools

This is one of those that's very difficult to Google, and also extremely frustrating.

With Chrome Devtools Console open, when I begin to type the word `var`, when I press the `a` in `var`, the Devtools window responds as if it has received a keyboard shortcut to close, and closes.

- Typing `va` in other textboxes/input areas (for example: this one) just does what it's supposed to (types `va`).
- Typing `v` followed by any other letter just does what it's supposed to.
- Typing `a` by itself, or followed by any other letter does what it supposed to.
- Typing any letter followed by an `a` does what it supposed to.
- I've opened the OSK and can confirm that there are no sticky keys pressed and that the only two letters that the only two letters being pressed are `v` followed by an `a`.
- I've tested known keyboard shortcuts with various modifiers, to see if I could identify a meta key that was stuck:  For example, I focused on a chrome window and typed `t` to test if `CTRL` was stuck, as `CTRL+T` would open a new tab.  Nothing showed up there.
- I've looked through the keyboard shortcuts in chrome to see if there were any hints there.  There were none.
- I've created a javascript method that listened for keypress input and logged the keys pressed.  (This one is suspect, because I can attach a handler to the window, but I don't believe thet console pays any attention to keypress handlers on itself).
- I've updated / restarted Chrome.

This is the weirdest, most specific computer problem I've ever had.  As I have occasion to type `var` in the Chrome developer tools console frequently, I would greatly like to resolve this.  It's driving me a bit crazy.

**NOTE**:  Because I wouldn't believe it if someone else told me, I've made a gif to demonstrate this behavior (note - this is site independent.  I just used stackoverflow, because I had an open tab).

[image: Chrome Devtools Console bug]